# Xamaring Forms Page Load Order Changes

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin form where I have a list and two buttons.  What I am seeing is that, depending where the buttons are, the model loads differently.  Here is my Xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.RewardsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"  
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MyApp.Models" x:DataType="local:RewardsViewModel"
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="650" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                SelectionMode="None" Grid.Row="1" >            
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:RewardModel">
                        <Label Text="{Binding id, StringFormat='ID: {0}'}" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                            FontSize="16" />
                         <!--other labels removed for brevity-->
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.Footer>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Text="Previous Month" Command="{Binding PreviousMonthCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
                    <Button Text="Next Month" Command="{Binding NextMonthCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </CollectionView.Footer>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The code works fine here.  But, if I move the StackLayout from the CollectionView.Footer to its own grid row, like this:

```
</CollectionView>
   <!--other labels removed for brevity-->
</CollectionView>
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
   <Button Text="Previous Month" Command="{Binding PreviousMonthCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
    <Button Text="Next Month" Command="{Binding NextMonthCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Then the code in my RewardsViewModel executes in a different order.  Here is my RewardsViewModel code (simplified):

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(CurrentMonth), nameof(CurrentMonth))]
[QueryProperty(nameof(CurrentYear), nameof(CurrentYear))]
public class RewardsViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<RewardModel> Items { get; }
    private List<MonthModel> months;
    private int _current_year;
    private int _current_month;
    public Command PreviousMonthCommand { get; }
    public Command NextMonthCommand { get; }
    
    public RewardsViewModel()
    {              
        Items = new ObservableCollection<RewardModel>();
        PreviousMonthCommand = new Command(OnPrevious, ValidatePrevious);
        NextMonthCommand = new Command(OnNext, ValidateNext);            
    }
    public int CurrentYear
    {
        get
        {
            return _current_year ;
        }
        set
        {
            _current_year = value;               
            LoadItems();
        }
    }
    public int CurrentMonth
    {
        get
        {
            return _current_month;
        }
        set
        {
            _current_month= value;                
            LoadItems();
        }
    }
 
    public void LoadItems()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        //do stuff
    }
    private bool ValidatePrevious()
    {
         //do stuff to validate and return true or false 
    }
    private bool ValidateNext()
    {  
        //do stuff to validate and return true or false          
    }
    private void OnPrevious()
    {
       //do stuyff
    }
    private void OnNext()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Depending on where the buttons reside in the Xaml page, the load events change:

1. When the buttons are within CollectionView, and the page loads, first the constructor loads then the Query Parameter setters load (CurrentMonth set then  CurrentYear set)
2. When the buttons are outside the CollectionView, first the constructor loads then ValidatePrevious method is called and then ValidateNext method is called.

Why does the placement of the buttons in the Xaml file change the order of operations in my ViewModel?  And, how do I ensure that the Query Parameter setters are called first, regardless of where the buttons reside?

**Edit:**
This is the code, from the previous page, that loads this page, passing in the Query Parameters:

```
async void OnItemSelected(MonthModel item)
{
   if (item == null)
      return;
   await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(RewardsPage)}?{nameof(RewardsViewModel.CurrentYear)}={CurrentYear}&CurrentMonth={SelectedItem.month}");
}
```

**Edit:  Adding Base Class:**

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {     
      
        bool isBusy = false;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return isBusy; }
            set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
        }

        string title = string.Empty;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
            [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
            Action onChanged = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
                return false;

            backingStore = value;
            onChanged?.Invoke();
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;

            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: `QueryProperty` is often used on [Page when navigating in shell project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation?WT.mc_id=shelldata-blog-jamont#process-navigation-data-using-query-property-attributes) ,why you need to use on a viewmodel ?

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the best way to do this, but this page is being loaded when a user clicks on an item in a list, from the previous page.  When the user clicks an item, my code loads the next page with the ID's of the item they clicked.  I will add that code, if it helps.

Comment: I'm not understanding the symptoms. How/where are `ValidatePrevious` and `ValidateNext` being called? (other than the button xaml) Commands should only happen when user clicks on the corresponding button. Which is not related to going to another page.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve That is what I am having a hard time understanding too!  I just updated my question to include the RewardsViewModel BaseViewModel, though I am not sure it would help?

Comment: That is to say, the ValidatePrevious and ValidateNext methods are not being used, yet, except in the constructor, where it is passed to the command button events.  The symptoms are that, depending on where my buttons are placed in the XAML form, the page lifecycle changes, and the Query  Parameters get set later or earlier, depending on the location of the buttons

Comment: I don't see code to set CurrentMonth. Instead of trying to ensure code is run in a certain order, need to write the code such that it doesn't matter what order it runs in. To say it another way, either some binding needs to update dynamically (public `property` with `OnPropertyChanged` in `setter`), or some action/update needs to be *deferred* until ready. To help you do that, need to see the code that sets CurrentMonth (or whatever value is wrong), and any code that calls that setter.